# missing right parenthesis when using if

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to use simple IF query in sql developer (Oracle), but i get 'missing right parenthesis' Error. I want to write all `ID` from my table `TEST_TABLE`, and write yes if `ID` is 1234, else 'no'. What am i doing wrong?

```
select id, if(id = 1234, 'yes', 'no') from TEST_TABLE t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't use IF there (IF is for control flow in PLSQL code, not queries), use CASE WHEN instead:

```
select id, CASE WHEN id = 1234 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END as idIs1234 from TEST_TABLE t
```

The basic form of a case when is:

```
CASE 
  WHEN test THEN truevalue 
 [WHEN othertest THEN othertruevalue] 
 [ELSE falsevalue ]
END
```

CASE must do one or more tests that each return a single value. If no case matches (all tests are false) and there is no ELSE clause, null is returned.

There is also a form that tests a single variable for equality against various values:

```
CASE id WHEN 1234 THEN 'yes1' WHEN 2345 THEN 'yes2' ELSE 'no' END
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. When can i use IF and what's its difference with CASE WHEN?

Comment: In simplistic terms "you can only use IF in a stored procedure, to choose which set of code statements to execute"